# Безопасность пользовательских данных

Tags: безопасность, php, javascript

Только только приступаю к веб программированию. И первым шагом делаю регистрационную форму, вход на сайт через БД соединение. И параллельно же хочу заняться их безопасностью.

Что посоветуете прочитать для этого?

Хочу защитить данные от несанкционированного доступа, от инъекций и т.д

И еще хочу спросить про MD5 кеширование. Насколько она актуальна на сегодняшний день? Я как то читал что такое кеширование легко взламывать.

Последний вопрос, записывать данные в БД старой доброй PHP или JavaScript? Что эффективнее или перспективнее, надеюсь вы поняли что имею в виду. Или без разницы?

Благодарю за ответы заранее и просьба не злиться из за 'глупых для вас' вопросов. :)

Comment: md5(hash('gost', $salt.md5($salt))) - удачи во взломе

Comment: извините, тут 'gost' это? Это просто string, да?

     string md5 ( string $str )

А $salt что за переменная? Ей так же присвоить любое выражение?

Comment: @navi1893, gost - это алгоритм шифрования. Они разными бывают. Подробнее здесь http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.hash.php

$salt - это примесь к паролю, для большей безопасности. Состоит из рандомного набора символов. Как эту соль генерировать - решать вам. Ее нужно хранить в отдельном поле.

Answer (score 4):

Для защиты от sql иньекций используйте PDO

Вместо md5 надо использовать crypt()

Answer (score 0):

Javascript сразу отпадает, его можно отключить и все.
Только php при посылке данных передача POST`ом обязательно проверять strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['field_name'])); Если есть пароль шифровать md5, так же советую генерировать соль и подсыпать ее к паролю, не забывая о том что соль и шифрованный пароль должны хранится в разных полях в БД.

Comment: если пропустить через htmlspecialchars, strip_tags уже не сработает, ибо html-сущности strip_tags не хавает